# Question mark in citation using Bibtex

Tags: latex, bibtex

Today I opened my `Latex` document and suddenly all citations turned to `[?]`. What surprised me is that everything was just perfect but suddenly today I found this issue. Has anyone faced such an issue before? If so, would you mind providing me how you solved it?

I use `Texpad` in Mas OSX.

Thank you

Comment: It means your references have changed and you need to rerun your document processor (`pdflatex` or whatever) to recompute them.

Comment: Try taking a look at this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/question-mark-instead-of-number-for-reference Hope this helps :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes you are right. It worked! Thank you very much

Comment: @hackergirl808 Maybe you can post this as an answer so that it can be accepted and the topic can be closed properly

Answer (score 1):

This is because your references have changed. Take a look at this link. It explains your problem very well and gives solutions. Good luck! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/question-mark-instead-of-number-for-reference